# Ideas for how to hide an 8ft sewer vent pole in backyard

Tags: landscaping, design, backyard

I have a sewer vent pole in my backyard (about 8 feet tall) and I'm looking for ideas on how to best hide it. I haven't seen any fake rocks etc that would be large enough to cover or hide it so I've been thinking maybe plant something near or on it or maybe build something around it. I've included a picture (I've temporarily stacked rocks on top of the manhole area), any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q40y.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

There a few ideas out there. Not sure what your exactly looking for.

Best I could come up with is...

Hide the sewer vent post with a custom built wooden or metal slip-over post with a solar light. (Light post) Although you would probably have to add a vent. 
[image: Light Post]

Finish it off with a wooden planter box over the man-hole.

Answer (score 1):

Basketball backboard, or less obtrusive: mini-weatherstation.

Comment: I like the weather station idea. It really lends a purpose built quality to the post being there.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I think I went overkill with it. Might need to deconstruct and dial it back a bit haha. Maybe staining it will help? I sort of went with more of a bar type of structure... [image]

Comment: How about tying those goats to it?